# How to use a bash script in Alpine Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, alpine-linux

I'm interested in using [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to make one service in Docker-Compose wait for another, using images based on the Alpine Linux distribution.

However, if I clone the `wait-for-it` repository and add to it the following `Dockerfile`,

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk --update add bash
COPY wait-for-it.sh wait-for-it.sh
CMD ["./wait-for-it.sh", "www.google.com:80"]
```

Then I build it using `docker build --tag waitforit .` followed by `docker run waitforit`, but I get this error message:

```
timeout: can't execute '15': No such file or directory
wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for www.google.com:80
```

By contrast, this is what I see when running this command on my (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) computer:

```
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for www.google.com:80
wait-for-it.sh: www.google.com:80 is available after 0 seconds
```

It seems like the bash script is not working in the Alpine container as it is on my Ubuntu local machine. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the executable of wait-for-it.sh? See its first line. #!/bin/bash or sh?

Comment: Seems like your shell script contains an error. Please paste the script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `wait-for-it` script isn't sh compliant, so you'd need to install `bash` into your alpine image.

However, may I suggest avoiding "hacks" like this and utilising `HEALTHCHECK` instead?

For example, having one service wait for another to be healthy would look like this:

```
services:
  my_service:
    image: something
    healthcheck:
      test: nc -z 3306

  other_service
  depends_on:
    my_service:
      condition: service_healthy
```

Please note, this will only work with `v2` compose file, not `v3`

Comment: Indeed I later found [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for), which is based on `wait-for-it` but is `alpine` compliant. As for [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck), from what I can tell from the documentation it runs __interval__ seconds after the container starts, and then again __interval__ seconds after each previous check completes. In my case, however, I'd like to run the check just once, before running the actual app, and block till it passes.

Comment: As you can read in docker compose v3 `depends_on` is no longer supported:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

"
- `depends_on` does not wait for `db` and `redis` to be “ready” before starting `web` - only until they have been started. If you need to wait for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.
- Version 3 no longer supports the `condition` form of `depends_on`.
- The `depends_on` option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with a version 3 Compose file.

Answer (score 2):

If you got here as I did looking for solutions to the "No such file or directory" error running scripts in Alpine, another thing to check is that your script has unix line endings.

In my case, I was saving the script in windows and adding it into the docker image and it was giving that same unhelpful error message.